# SQL query:: number= select query in where clause

Tags: sql

I am not able to understand this query:

```
SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE 3 = (
    SELECT COUNT(FIELD1)
    FROM TABLE1 T2
    WHERE T2.FIELD1 <= T1.FIELD1
);
```

This query is running properly with out any error. The inner count query is returning result as 363.
in where clause if I put `3 = (select..` then I am getting one result. If I put `4=(select..` then no records are coming. If I put `363 = (select...` then 3 records are coming.

I am confused with this. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query produces a result set consisting of the bottom `n` records in `table1` with respect to the ordering implied by the values of `field1` where `n`represents the literal number in the where clause. a non-empty result sets to the query also asserts that there are exactly `n` tuples to meet the comparison criterion.

you therefore compute the occupants of the `n`th rank in a tournament provided that the rank can be issued unequivocally.

example:

imagine a tournament result as follows:

1. scooby doo
2. donald duck
3. mickey mouse
4. calvin
   hobbes

6.  minnie mouse
...

363. whoever

this ranking would be compatible with your results (of course you would commonly label calvin & hobbes' rank as 4 instead of 5, as you'd have to if using your query to dertemine top `n` contestants).

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is counting how many `FIELD1` values in the whole table are smaller or equal compared to the current one in the outer query (`T1.FIELD1`). Therefore the whole queue just works like this:

> Return `FIELD1` values from table `TABLE1` if there are exactly 3 (or 4 or
>   whatever number you put there) other `FIELD1` values in the table `TABLE1`
>   which are smaller or equal.

Note that it uses `<=` which means the subquery will allways return at least 1.

Comment: shouldn't it be '_smaller_ or equal compared to the current one' ?